# How to implement onClickListener and onLongClickListener in a single viewholder?

Tags: java, android, android-viewholder

I'm trying, but when I implement both at the same time, the ViewHolder cannot reach none of those. Is it possible? My code:

```
public final class SomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    public final AestheticTextView mName;
    public final AestheticTextView mNumber;

    public SomeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mName = (AestheticTextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        mNumber = (AestheticTextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // doesn't run
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        // doesn't run
    }
}
```

If I remove one of the listeners, like below, it works fine.

```
public final class SomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public final AestheticTextView mName;
    public final AestheticTextView mNumber;

    public SomeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mName = (AestheticTextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        mNumber = (AestheticTextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // run properly
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point, but I return a boolean, since implementation requires it.

Comment: Do you return true or false?

Comment: True #words to complete minimum length#

Answer (score -1):

Create a bind method or whatever you want to call it.

```
public void bind(ModelClass model, MyInterface listener) {

itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
//Create your own interface and add arguments based on your needs
                    listener.itemClicked(view);
                }
            });

itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
    //Create your own interface and add arguments based on your needs
                        listener.itemLongClicked(view);
                    }
                });
}
```

> On your `onBindViewHolder()`

```
holder.bind(item.get(position), listener);
```

> And when declaring your `Adapter`

```
    adapter = new MyAdapter(item, new OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void itemClicked(View view, ModelClass model) {
            //event
        }
        @Override
        public void itemLongClicked(View view, ModelClass model) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: But this would be the same as implementing both listeners directly inside constructor, which I can actually do, but seems to be considered a bad practice.